# Django-Mysql Data Migration

Tags: mysql, django, migration

I wanna know the simplest and easy way of doing that:

I have a model called Student, and many Students in a database with many attributes, like:

**Name  Type**

id  int(11)

name    varchar(200)

sex varchar(1)

status  int(11)

created datetime

What I want to do is to rename the model to Costumer and make the "status" field be a Charfield (varchar) instead of integer. And I have to keep the data in the database intact.

Answer (score 2):

Open your self to the world of [SOUTH](http://south.aeracode.org/). South is an intelligent schema and data migrations for  Django projects.

AFter installation and putting 'south' in your django settings installed_apps list you would like to run 2 commands.

1. python manage.py schemamigration [my_app_name] --initial #initial is used when you run it for the first time
2. AFter step 1 you would have a folder named 'migrations' in your app folder, now you would have to apply the migration by doing python manage.py migrate [my_app_name]

After applying the migration you can check the status of your migration by running python manage.py migrate [my_app_name] --list. The migrations with an * have been applied.

Answer (score 0):

> create table costumer ( id int(11),
>
> name varchar(200),
>
> sex varchar(1),
>
> status varchar(20)
>   created datetime );
>
> insert into costumer select id,name,sex,cast(status as char), created from
>   student;

Then of course edit your django to match.

Answer (score 0):

IF, there are no other models that refer to Student, then you can do this:

1. Backup of your database first, make sure you can restore from it (into another, different database)
2. Update the python code of your django model
3. Have django create the new table (for your renamed model):

   ```
   python manage.py syncdb
   ```
4. Copy data from the old table to the new:

   ```
   echo 'insert into costumer select id, name, sex, cast(status as char), created from student;' | python manage.py dbshell
   ```

However, if you have other models that refer to the old table, using foreign keys or manytomany relations, then the above will not work, as those other models may have references in their database schemas to the old table. If that's your case then you can try this:

1. Dump all your models to json

   ```
   python manage.py dumpdata --indent 4 > everything.json
   ```
2. Update your django model
3. Have Django create the new table (for your renamed model):

   ```
   python manage.py syncdb
   ```
4. Edit the json file manually, replace the pattern `"model": "yourapp.student"` with `"model": "yourapp.costumer"`. You might have to do other replacements, depending on your models and the relationships between them.
5. Reload the json

   ```
   python manage.py loaddata
   ```

And for the future, see the answer by @mangobug and start using `django-south`.